# Get importSpec for unresolved identifiers

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to understand what https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#File means by "unresolved identifiers" and how to resolve the ast.ImportSpec from this.

I have an interface:

```
import "github.com/elgohr/counterfeiter/fixtures/aliased_package"

type SomethingWithForeignInterface interface {
     the_aliased_package.InAliasedPackage
}
```

As you can see, **the_aliased_package** is different from the imported **aliased_package**. Nevertheless, it's inside this import (but the foldername of the package is different).
In the ast.File representation of this interface, ast.File.Imports contains a Path.Value "github.com/elgohr/counterfeiter/fixtures/aliased_package"
and Unresolved contains an ast.Ident.Name "the_aliased_package"

How can I resolve the unresolved ident to the right import?

Comment: Did you only parse the file or have you also type-checked it with a valid `types.Importer` implementation?

Comment: The file came from parser.ParseDir -> pkg.Files -> file

Comment: Take a look at [`types.Importer`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Importer). I believe its one line* documentation answers your question. *"How can I resolve the unresolved ident to the right import?"*

Comment: `types.Importer` looks like the thing I'm looking for. Do you have a tip for an easy implementation? Walker looks huge...

Comment: Actually that's not gonna help you directly. The only place I can see where the `Unresolved` slice contents are attempted to be resolved is here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/go/ast/resolve.go#L160-L168 and there the resolving depends on the provided scope and possibly also the importer. I'm not really sure how to do that if it indeed is possible.

Comment: But with the previously mentioned `types.Importer` and additionally `types.Config` you can get your hands on an object of type `*types.Package` which contains the name `the_aliased_package` and the path `"github.com/elgohr/counterfeiter/fixtures/aliased_package"`. Just not through the `Unresolved` field... If you're interested I can provide a simple example.

Comment: .. something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ty9gZWffvb6

Comment: conf.Check calls NewPackage(path, "") for the returned pkg.
In this way pkg.Name is always empty...

Comment: I am able to make the code work as illustrated by the link to the playground. If you can please share your code how you've implemented it.

Comment: See https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/issues/87
I was just wondering how to get the fset. In this way I had a look into conf.Check. There I found out that the function just returns 
(NewPackage(path, ""), NewChecker(conf, fset, pkg, info).Files(files)). In this way I'm wondering how this might work...

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/903f095c1ae3cafc40855662c69722121c42e3a7/src/go/types/api.go#L351 as you can see `pkg` is then passed to `NewChecker` on which the `Files` method is called, that then probably modifies the `pkg` so that it has a name, and what not. Like for example here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/903f095c1ae3cafc40855662c69722121c42e3a7/src/go/types/check.go#L183-L202

Comment: The linked issue, does not seem to be relevant to this.

Comment: Just think about it, if you actually want the identifier `the_aliased_package` referenced in file X to be associated with the imported package you have to parse that package to actually find out that even though the import says `".../aliased_package"`, the actual package declaration at the top of the package's files says `pacakge the_aliased_package`. How else would you know it if you only parse file X? That's why you need to use the Importer and Config/Chekcer approach, because the importer *resolves the import path*.

Comment: Looks like even this solution can't resolve the right package. Got: `something_remote.go:4:2: could not import github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/fixtures/aliased_package (can't find import: "github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/fixtures/aliased_package")`
Which totally makes sense, because the package name is the_aliased_package

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the aliased name. The error says it can't find a package at the given path. Are you using the default importer or the source importer? The default one has no problem resolving std lib packages but I frequently find it has problems with some other packages and I haven't yet discerned what the cause is. When I want to import a non std lib package I always end up using the source impoter.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your patience!